# What's the difference between startGearmanServer and createGearmanServer in Gearman?

Tags: gearman

What's the difference between startGearmanServer and createGearmanServer in Gearman.

```
gearman = Gearman.createGearman();
GearmanServer server = gearman.createGearmanServer("127.0.0.1", POST);
```

and startGearmanServer code:

```
Gearman gearman = Gearman.createGearman();
GearmanServer server = gearman.startGearmanServer(POST);
```

Answer (score 0):

startGearmanServer: instantiate a GearmanServer.
createGearmanServer: just get GearmanServer.